# Receive XCAV token to sporran wallet

Tags: polkadot-js, did, kilt

We've minted some ERC20 tokens `XCAV coins` on our node. Can the Sporran wallet receive `XCAV token`? I transfer `XCAV` and it success but I didn't saw any token in wallet.

Someone please give some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sporran wallet only supports KILT coins. There is a development version which also supports the coins of the testnet Peregrine (PILT).